# Reset Password link is missing dot in the domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, firefox

When i click on forgot password in my application, it sends a mail with reset password link But the link is broken.

For example : 
Expected reset link contains "subdomain.domain.com"
Actual reset link contains "subdomaindomain.com" or subdomain.domaincom"

code base is on ruby on rails

Comment: Look for `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` value.

Comment: @MarekLipka In config.action_mailer.default_url_options we have mentioned the proper value  and ie., "subdomain.domain.com". But we are facing this issue for few users and not for all users